# Single word for inveigling someone to lower their guard

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I’m looking for a verb with the rough meaning of softening someone’s guard, leaving them more open to attack. However, **it should be a verb that means to make *a target* soften their guard.**

It’s for the name of game ability, in a cycle with similar abilities (all with one-word names).

Ideally it would be the opposite of “intimidate”, but more elegant than “unintimidate”.

---

For nerd context, it’s a Pokémon Ability that lowers foes’ Defense, instead of their Attack like Intimidate. So ideally it would be a verb that the *user* performs, instead of one that the target does.

The Ability is for Pokémon that look weak, cute, or otherwise nonthreatening, so that their opponent doesn’t take the fight as seriously, making them less wary.

Comment: Relax is a word you could use but it's kind of just part of that meaning.

Comment: *Disarm*, *regroup, lick your wounds, retrench, reduce forces, take a laundry day, lower shields.*

Comment: What exactly does this *guard* mean: like a shield or an ability to dodge?

Comment: @Boondoggle: I would say their wariness and alertness; it goes on Pokémon that look so unassuming or nonthreatening that the foe relaxes a bit

Comment: Who’s point if view do you want to express? The title does not match the text. The title asks about letting one’s guard down, The text seems to ask about making another let their guard down. If it is the latter, what is wrong with soften?

Comment: @Damila: good point, I updated the title

Comment: Puss in Boots used [*big-eyes*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Puss_in_Boots_Widening_His_Eyes.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **lull**

> to give or lead to feel a false sense of safety; cause to be less alert, aware, or watchful

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lull

Comment: i like it.. to lull someone into a false sense of security  ..

Comment: Certainly what most would use. But how often is 'lull' used standalone ('to lull someone') without 'into a false sense of security'? This is, after all, a SWR.

Answer (score 2):

**beguile** definition at [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/beguile)

> - to influence by trickery, flattery, etc.; mislead; delude
> - to charm or divert

Comment: There's an endless number of synonyms for seduce, enchant, bewitch, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I read this as:
 - One Pokemon uses Tail Whip, lowers enemy's defense stat
 - Looking for a name for the ailment/debuff on the enemy

Similar to how one Pokemon could use Thunderwave, to "Stun" an enemy, which inflicts a "Stunned" debuff

In most RPGs this kind of debuff (a stat debuff) generally doesn't have a name, 
but I think if you really want one, you could try "**Exposed** (weakness)". 
It best paints the image of weakened guard for me

> Bulbasaur used *Leer*, it **Exposed** the Charmander!

Answer (score 0):

How about **relax**?

It’s listed in [Merriam Webster’s](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20one's%20guard%20down) definition for *let one's guard down*:

> to **relax** and stop being careful and alert

Answer (score 0):

The word **blandishment** refers to pleansantries,  flattery, gentle or coaxing language of some kind, with the intention of making the person so blandished more receptive to something the blandisher has in mind. Not sure whether it would fit with Pokemon since I know nothing about the game and whether there is any opportunity for the players to communicate using language.

Answer (score -1):

Dismantle. I believe this is the word your looking for.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismantle) gives:

> 1 : to disconnect the pieces of
>
> will have to dismantle the engine 
>
> *also* : to destroy the integrity or functioning of
>
> The program was later dismantled due to a lack of funding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tyler, I added a source to help get you started; now it's up to you to support your answer.